# What Z stand for in leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i am new in leaflet js. so reading many basic article and write up on this to understand leaflet js.see the code and tell me what is the utility of z ?

```
L.tileLayer('**http://localhost/tileserver/tile.aspx?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}**', {
    minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 16,
    attribution: 'My Tile Server'
}).addTo(map);
```

i know z means here zoom but what zoom will be doing in leaflet js ?
i have seen a folder is consider as z.

anyone can guide me about z, x and y and tell me why we need to access any image like this way. if possible discuss with example. thanks

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#url-template

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand about a `zoom` functionality in a mapping API?

Comment: i just like to know what zoom does in leaflet?

Comment: zoom means here a folder location or it has any separate meaning and usage ?

Comment: There's no additional information on Zoom as it is such a basic concept to maps (and images).   Open the leaflet home page: http://leafletjs.com/ - see the map?  see the [+] and [-] buttons?  click those - that's zoom in and out.  The z value sets this when the map is first loaded.

Comment: so when we create tiles from a big images then what zoom level i should set? it is not getting clear to me what zoom level i should set during tile creation. based on what parameter people set zoom level during tile creation. share the idea. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Zoom level 0 shows the entire earth in 256*256 pixels. The next level (z1) needs 512*512 pixels to show the entire earth (4 squares of 256*256 pixels). Every new zoom levels means 4 times the number of tiles needed to show an area.

A more detailed article, "how web maps work", can be found here: https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-web-maps-work/